# Get Value of Toggle element from Office Fabric UI

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fabricjs

I am trying to get the value of a toggle button from the office fabric ui.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric-js/components/toggle/toggle

html:

```
<div class="ms-Toggle">
  <span class="ms-Toggle-description">Let apps use my location</span> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="demo-toggle-3" class="ms-Toggle-input" />
  <label for="demo-toggle-3" class="ms-Toggle-field" tabindex="0">
    <span class="ms-Label ms-Label--off">Off</span> 
    <span class="ms-Label ms-Label--on">On</span> 
  </label>
</div>
```

javascript to initialize the toggler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ToggleElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-Toggle");
  for (var i = 0; i < ToggleElements.length; i++) {
    new fabric['Toggle'](ToggleElements[i]);
  }
</script>
```

The problem is I am not sure how to get the value of `On` or `Off`.

I usually would use `document.querySelector('input.demo-toggle-3').textConent` but since this isn't a textfield it was coming up as `undefined`

Any suggestions to get the On or Off value of the Fabric ui toggler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple trick

When the toggle is on, the label gets the `is-selected` class.

You could grab it with something like `#demo-toggle-3 + .is-selected`.
(The selector takes the adjacent element after and element with id=`demo-toggle-3` if it also has the class `is-selected`

### Working demo

```js
var ToggleElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-Toggle");
for (var i = 0; i < ToggleElements.length; i++) {
  new fabric['Toggle'](ToggleElements[i]);
}


function isSelected() {
  var state = document.querySelector('#demo-toggle-3 + .is-selected') != null;
  console.log(state);
  return state;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css" />
<script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div class="ms-Toggle">
  <span class="ms-Toggle-description">Let apps use my location</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="demo-toggle-3" class="ms-Toggle-input" />
  <label for="demo-toggle-3" class="ms-Toggle-field" tabindex="0">
    <span class="ms-Label ms-Label--off">Off</span> 
    <span class="ms-Label ms-Label--on">On</span> 
  </label>
</div>

<button onclick="isSelected()">IsSelected?</button>
```

Comment: Using just `var state = document.querySelector('#demo-toggle-3 + .is-selected') != null;
  console.log(state);` inside of my code did the trick for me. That is pure genious (using the `.is-selected`class. Thank you again